# Split a string from JSON and display it in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller="countryCtrl">
  <div class="m-b-20" ng-repeat="val in records">
    {{val.Country}} <br>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('countryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [{
      "Country": "Germany,France,UK,Japan"
    }, {
      "Country": "Sweden,Australia,USA"
    }, {
      "Country": "Mexico,Colombia,Brazil"
    }, {
      "Country": "Austria,UAE,Kenya"
    }]
  }])
```

Instead of displaying country in a string need to split the countries and display it as bullet points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`string.split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
<div class="m-b-20" ng-repeat="val in records">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="country in val.Country.split(',')">{{ country }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rzf4px0c/)

Answer (score 3):

The less repeats and filters the better.  Handle the change in your controller so the template isn't watching too much.  Simple way to handle it is to create a directive and split it when it gets added.  [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/rsy6j1n4/). Steps are simple:

Update your template

```
<div class="m-b-20" ng-repeat="val in ::records">
    <country my-country="{{::val.Country}}"> </country>
</div>
```

Add a new directive.  Feel free to replace the template with your markup:

```
  angular.module('app').directive('country', CountryDirective);

  /* @ngInject */
  function CountryDirective ($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template:'<ul><li ng-repeat="c in ::countries">{{c}}</li></ul>',
      controller: CountryDirectiveController,
      scope:{
        'myCountry':'@'
      }
    };


    /* @ngInject */
    function CountryDirectiveController ($scope) {


      onCountryChange();

      /*
       //You only need this if you dont use  '@' if you need = or < you might need to take special care to make sure its bound.  
      $scope.$watch('myCountry', onCountryChange);
      */
      function onCountryChange(){
         $scope.countries = ($scope.myCountry || '').split(',').map(function(i){ return i.trim()});
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in more angular way by creating a filter to split the string by providing split character.

In your html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="countryCtrl">
  <div class="m-b-20" ng-repeat="val in records">
     <ul>
        <!-- Use the filters to split the string values -->
        <li ng-repeat="country in val.Country | split:','">{{ country }}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Filter

```
app
   .filter('split', function() {
       return function(input, separator) {
           // returns an array
           return input.split(separator);
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer